# Translation error: Lesebeiträge

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, careers-germany

In Careers, I was asked to add more "Lesebeiträge" (which is German for reading contributions), but the Link leads me to https://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/edit/...#writing, which is about writing contributions.

I suggest to correct the text on the link to "Schreibbeiträge" (writing contributions).

[image: Lesebeiträge instead of Schreibbeiträge]

Maybe also important: it's really the text, not the link which is incorrect, since I already have 8 reading contributions but only 2 writing contributions.

Comment: As a German native speaker I have no idea what a "Lesebeitrag" is supposed to be and "Schreibbeitrag" isn't much better.

Comment: It appears to be the words they chose for the German localization of the "Reading" and "Writing" sections of the profile page. Strange word choice in any case for "things I've read" and "things I've written"

Comment: I agree that "Schreibbeitrag" is a very *very* rare word which basically nobody uses and it just sounds odd to most people.

Comment: "Lesebeitrag" isn't technically wrong; but it's generally only used by newspapers for articles written by readers or other guest authors AFAIK.

Comment: @sloth wouldn't that be "Leserbeitrag" though? I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: I agree with @TimSeguine it would be "Leserbeitrag"

Comment: Anyway the word "Beitrag" seems too specific for the intended meaning.

Comment: I'd suggest terms like "*Schriften*" or "*Werke*", even though these sound a bit archaic. Maybe it's better to translate "contributions" with "*Leistung*", the terms "Schreibleistungen" and "Leseleistung" still are a bit odd but one at least knows what is meant.

Comment: can someone explain what "reading/writing contributions" are at all?

Comment: @TimSeguine No, "Lesebeitrag" is the correct word (because you, as the reader of the newspaper, are supposed to read it). As with "Schreibbeitrag", it's not a very common word, but it certainly exists.

Comment: Is reading contribution "I've worked on a book/paper by reviewing it to improve its quality" or "I've read a book and know its content"? Writing content might better be "Veröffentlichungen" but not sure whether this is used for things like blog postings too.

Comment: @sloth both seem to exist, but "Leserbeitrag" is more widely used by a factor of about 100.

Comment: @Micka maybe another native speaker can comment on that. I thought of "Veröffentlichungen" as well since it shows up that way on CVs.

Comment: @TimSeguine I'm native german, but don't know what is intended to be covered by "Writings" and "Readings". "Veröffentlichungen" (mostly scientific papers) and "Fachliteratur" are german words that cover most of the stuff that's relevant to one's career, but it wouldnt cover readings and writing of different topics and might be too specific. Afaik in german CVs it's not common to add "things that I've read" in any way...

Comment: @Micka I get the impression from the English site that it is supposed to cover things like blog posts or articles on personal websites as well.

Comment: @TimSeguine Yes, "Leserbeitrag" is more widely used, but it's not the same as "Lesebeitrag". "Veröffentlichungen" is quite formal and sounds more like a scientific journal published your article and not something you wrote on your blog. "Fachartikel" or "Fachbeiträge" would work, but it would be odd if it would link to your own blog instead of say a magazine or website with some credibility.

Comment: @sloth seems like it might be a good idea to start a discussion about the word choice for this on http://german.stackexchange.com/ This comment thread is getting off the rails a bit.

Comment: This post is under discussion at: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/20449/besseres-wort-f%C3%BCr-lesebeitrag-in-careers-original-reading

Comment: Whatever you want to call it, it certainly is not a __spelling__ mistake, though. In German you create new words ad lib simply by adding any two nouns together.. 'Beiträge' sounds good enough for me.

Comment: @Bergi Just to be clear on this: No, "Schriften", "Werke" and "Schreibleistung" are all completely out of the question I'm afraid. No speaker of German would use those given the context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Great discussion, thanks a lot for all the feedback! Here's the fix we've made after going through the comments above and on the [German SE question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/20449/besseres-wort-f%C3%BCr-lesebeitrag-in-careers-original-reading):

**Profile page:**

[image]

**Completeness report:**

[image]

**Completeness suggestions:**

[image]

Comment: Your last screenshot appears to display a bug... :-). "bearbeiter" is overlapping the 193/210 and there's a larger than normal space between that and "vollstandig".

Comment: Ah, right. Another one of those "bearbeiten" vs "edit" styling bugs. Should be fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for reporting. We're taking a look at this. It appears there are two issues here. The first is that the text does not match the link (i.e. the translation is unambiguously wrong). For the time being, we'll change this to "Schreibbeiträge".

The second is whether "Schreibbeiträge" and "Lesebeiträge" are appropriate/understandable translations for "writings" and "readings". These English terms aren't super-common themselves, and were chosen for conciseness, so it's possible that something was lost in translation. More to follow...